# Cluster points in $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, metric-spaces

For any metric space $X$, there is a proposition that says a point $a\in X$ is a cluster point of a sequence $(x_n)$ of elements of $X$ iff there is some subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ which converges to $a$.

The extended real line $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ doesn't posses a natural metric. How can I prove the above proposition for a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ with cluster points in $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$? E.g. let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of elements of $\mathbb{R}$. Obviously the claim is reduced to the one stated above for a cluster point $a\in\mathbb{R}-\{\pm\infty\}$. I am having a bit of difficulty proving it for cluster points $\pm\infty$. The definitions I have are these:

> A subset $U\subset\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ is called a **neighborhood** of
> $\infty$ (resp. of $-\infty)$ if there is some $K>0$ such that
> $(K,\infty)\subset U$ (resp. $(-\infty,-K)\subset U$).
>
> Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\pm\infty$ is called
> a **cluster point** (resp. **limit**) of $(x_n)$ if each neighborhood $U$ of $\pm\infty$
> contains infinitely many (resp. almost all) terms of $(x_n)$.

So, suppose $\infty$ is a cluster point for a sequence $(x_n)$ of elements of $\mathbb{R}$. I would like to show that there exists some strictly increasing mapping $\phi:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ such that $\lim x_{\phi(n)}=\infty$. That is to say, I have to prove that
$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists m\in\mathbb{N})(\forall n\geq m)(\varepsilon<x_{\phi(n)}).$$
Since $\infty$ is a cluster point, there exits an infinite subset $M$ of natural numbers such that $x_n\in U$ for all $n\in M$ and all neighborhoods $U$ of $\infty$.

How can I construct $\phi$? Any suggestions?

Comment: The extended real line is indeed metrizable, in fact is is homeomorphic to $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ and $d(x,y)=|\arctan(x) -\arctan(y)|$ is one possible metric on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\infty$ is a cluster point of $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, there is an $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_{n_0}>0$. Suppose that we’ve chosen $n_k$ for $k\le m$ so that $n_0<n_1<\ldots<n_m$, and $x_{n_k}>k$ for $k=0,\ldots,m$. There is an $n_{m+1}\in\Bbb N$ such that $n_{m+1}>n_m$ and $x_{m+1}>m+1$. Thus, we can recursively construct a subsequence $\langle x_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ that converges to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call it natural, but you can define a metric $d$ on the extended line (denote the usual metric by $\rho(x,y)=|x-y|$) such that for $x$ **real** we have $\rho(x_n,x) \to 0$ **iff** $d(x_n,x) \to 0$.

Define $d(x,y) = |\arctan x - \arctan y|$ for $x,y$ real and $d(x,\infty) = |\arctan x -{\pi \over 2}|$ and a similar definition for $d(x,-\infty)$ and $d(-\infty, \infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the bijection$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\overline R&\longrightarrow&[-1,1]\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}\frac x{1+|x|}&\text{ if }x\in\Bbb R\\\pm1&\text{ if }x=\pm\infty.\end{cases}\end{array}$$The topology of $\overline{\Bbb R}$ is induced by the distance $d(x,y)=\bigl|f(x)-f(y)\bigr|$. So, since you know that the property that you are interested in holds for metric spaces, then it holds on $\overline{\Bbb R}$.